# Service brokers in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using the script at [Rusanu.com](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-to-a-background-procedure/) to call procedures with parameters asynchronously,

However, when ever I pass parameters based on which the procedures are called,somewhere around half of the procedures are executed only and rest of them are not.

For example:

This is how I call those procedures :

```
if @ZIP is not null
 exec usp_AsyncExecInvoke @procedureName = N'MatchZIP'
 , @p1 = @ZIP, @n1 = N'@ZIPFromUser'
 , @p2 = @checkbool, @n2='@checkbool'
 , @token = @token output;
```

Similarly,if I passed parameters for 10 procedures ,only 4-6 will be executed. What could be the reason ?

Comment: What have you researched?  Anything in the AsyncExecResults table?

Comment: To ask another question in the same vein as @DanGuzman, have you checked to make sure that all of the messages are making it to the service broker queue initially? Are there any left in the queue once the procedure stops executing?

Comment: @DanGuzman: I did . Infact, AnsynchExecResults table shows no errors at all.

Comment: @BenThul: I added checks to make sure that the procedure that is calling all those procedures in asynch via AsynchExecPorcedure does not exit until all the procedures that were started are done executing. I also used a function to know if all the procedures were making it to the service broker queue and indeed the number was less. The procedures  that are I do not get results from are never started either. I am quite doubtful if Service queue contains all those in first place.Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: A brief scan of the code shows that it uses internal activation (i.e. the `alter queue` statement that sets procedure_name). Disable activation and run your process again. All of the messages will be on the queue but nothing will process them. You can examine the queue with a `select * from queueName`.

Comment: @BenThul: Yes,If I deactivate the internal activation, I can see all of them sitting in the queue. How do I go about it ?

Comment: If I were troubleshooting this, I'd call the activation proc by hand and see if there's anything "funny" going on.